# Https WCF webservice giving Http 400 error while calling method from browser

Tags: wcf

I have created a wcf web service. When i run it for http it works fine and gives result in wcftestclient as well as browser.
  But when i test for https by changing it fot https it gives result in wcftestclient but when i try to call method from url by passing parameters. i receive error.
  HTTP 400 error
   It’s not you, it’s this link (it appears to be broken).

I have changed configuration file for https. It is working in wcftestclient but not in browser. it gives wsdl file but error for method calling.

I call method as 
      https://my-pc/Service.svc/LogIn?a;a

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We understand that a lot of people using SO do not speak English natively. I'd recommend having a co-worker or peer read your question and help you rewrite it using better spelling and grammar. As it is currently written it's very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way is Goto project properties of your WCF Service Project in Visual studio, open Web tab/page and make sure IIS web server is selected and IIS Express not selected mention your web address like https://localhost/WcfService1 and if virtual directory is not created then Click on "Create Virtual Directory Button", visual studio will create with required SSL settings for you.

To verify open Internet Information Manager(inetmgr), select service virtual directory/website and verify binding in Actions pane on the right hand side.
It should have two browse links under Manage Application heading one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

Hope this helps.